# Intermittent error from Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

Our issue started on Oct 5, prior to this there had been no issues, and there were no changes to our systems, servers, or software that we are aware of.

Seemingly randomly users will get an error when using our in house software which sends emails to other users and external customers,

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 
The request failed. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send ----> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ----> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

We've been tracking the error in our logs, and have been able to reproduce it in our test environment, but it is not consistent. We send hundreds of emails daily in our system, and we can go hours without seeing the error, then suddenly a user will get the error for a few minutes, and then it stops.

We have found others who have similar issues that are consistent (every email fails), but none that are random like this.

This is the code that sends the emails. It is in a WCF service on our servers which our desktop applications call:

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(networkUserName, networkPassword, networkDomain);
        service.Url = new Uri(exchangeServerUri);

        try
        {
            EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);

            if (toEmailAddress == null || toEmailAddress.Trim().Equals(""))
                throw new ArgumentException("To email address(es) required");

            email.ToRecipients.AddRange(toEmailAddress.Replace(",", ";").Replace(" ", "").TrimEnd(';').Split(';'));
            email.Subject = emailSubject;
            email.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, emailBody);
            email.Body.BodyType = htmlBody ? BodyType.HTML : BodyType.Text;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ccEmailAddress))
                email.CcRecipients.AddRange(ccEmailAddress.Replace(",", ";").Replace(" ", "").TrimEnd(';').Split(';'));

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bccEmailAddress))
                email.BccRecipients.AddRange(bccEmailAddress.Replace(",", ";").Replace(" ", "").TrimEnd(';').Split(';'));

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailSubject))
                email.Subject = emailSubject;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailPriority))
                switch (emailPriority.ToUpper())
                {
                    case "H":
                        email.Importance = Importance.High;
                        break;
                    case "L":
                        email.Importance = Importance.Low;
                        break;
                    default:
                        email.Importance = Importance.Normal;
                        break;
                }
            else
                email.Importance = Importance.Normal;

            if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
                foreach (AppFileAttachment attach in attachments)
                    email.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attach.FileName, attach.File);

            email.SendAndSaveCopy();
        }
        catch (Exception excError)
        {
            throw excError;
        }
```

Comment: Exchange OnPrem or Exchange Online?

Comment: Exchange Online

Comment: The place to start would be look at the response headers when it fails that might provide more details as to why its happening at that particular time.

Comment: All we get back from the call email.SendAndSaveCopy(); is the error included above. I tried a message trace and I don't find them in there either

Comment: Is it possible that this error is due to the 30/minute sending limit? Or would the error be more specific about that?

Comment: You should get a response from WebService in that case, what you seeing is just a protocol failure happening at either end (or along the routing path), if you run a fiddler capture at the same time as the failure that might help with headers etc

Comment: One of our customers has this as well, also when creating / modifying appointments, so seems to be pretty general. And the time it started happening looks similar as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have had the same error since two weeks ago. Users have reported more and more frequent random errors. **Unfortunately EWS is discontinued since July 2018**, although the community has been maintaining it (https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api).

I tried upgrade from the official package (`Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices`) to `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard` but, unfortunately, it did not fix the problem.

I'm not sure, but I *think* Microsoft is deploying a new version of the Exchange API that is incompatible with the old EWS, and this may be the reason why some requests work and others don't, depending on whether the server that received the request it's up to date or not.

The alternative offered by Microsoft is to migrate to [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

Here is my implementation with authentication by application, which generates a mail in a user's draft.

`var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var tenantId        = "my_tenant_Id";
var clientId        = "my_client_Id";
var clientSecret    = "my_client_secret";

var options = new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var message = new Message
    {
      Subject = "You danced it!",
      Importance = Importance.Low,
      Body = new ItemBody
      {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = @"Dale a tu cuerpo alegría Macarena.
                  <br/>Que a tu cuerpo es pa' darle alegría y cosa buena.
                  <br/><h3>¡¡¡¡¡ Ehhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh, MACARENA !!!!!!!"</h3>
      },
      ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
      {
        new Recipient
        {
          EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = "dest@xyz.com" }
        }
      },
    };

var msg = graphClient.Users["myUser@myCompany.com"].Messages.Request().AddAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Here are some links I found useful in putting this together:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service
- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/tree/main/#prerequisites
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp